# Refreshing JWT token in Passportjs

Tags: javascript, passport.js, openid-connect, auth0, onelogin

I am using passport-openidconnect strategy which works well but the expiration of the session is short 3600 seconds and I don't think its changeable.

Would I use the refresh token to get another token id?

If I do where would I add that logic in something like this? https://github.com/passport/express-4.x-openidconnect-example/blob/master/server.js

Answer (score 12):

The expiration of the session is configurable from the auth provider side. For e.g. let's say you are using `auth0` as your authentication provider, then you can configure the `token` timeout at app setting (https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/guides/access-token/set-access-token-lifetime)

[image]

As per as `refresh token` is concerned, passport itself doesn't support it and it's up-to us to implement it. For auth0, you can renew the token by following the flow at https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/refresh-token/current. I pasted the code from that link:

```
var request = require("request");

var options = { method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://YOUR_DOMAIN/oauth/token',
  headers: { 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
  form: 
   { grant_type: 'refresh_token',
     client_id: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
     client_secret: 'YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET',
     refresh_token: 'YOUR_REFRESH_TOKEN' } };

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);

  console.log(body);
});
```

OR you can use an add-on to passport https://github.com/fiznool/passport-oauth2-refresh

```
var passport = require('passport'),
  , refresh = require('passport-oauth2-refresh')
  , FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy;

var strategy = new FacebookStrategy({
  clientID: FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
  clientSecret: FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
  callbackURL: "http://www.example.com/auth/facebook/callback"
},
function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
  // Make sure you store the refreshToken somewhere!
  User.findOrCreate(..., function(err, user) {
    if (err) { return done(err); }
    done(null, user);
  });
});

passport.use(strategy);
refresh.use(strategy);

var refresh = require('passport-oauth2-refresh');
refresh.requestNewAccessToken('facebook', 'some_refresh_token', function(err, accessToken, refreshToken) {
  // You have a new access token, store it in the user object,
  // or use it to make a new request.
  // `refreshToken` may or may not exist, depending on the strategy you are using.
  // You probably don't need it anyway, as according to the OAuth 2.0 spec,
  // it should be the same as the initial refresh token.

});
```